# How to get Bookmarks from iphone safari

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, wkwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller

I want to list out bookmarks from my iphone safari in my iOS application.But I couldn't find any tutorial related to this.Please help me to get some idea.